# Is android registration necessery for development of android application?

Tags: android

Is android registration necessery for development of android application?

I am planning to develop application for android phones but dont know registration benefits & scopes for selling your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for publishing your application on the Android Marked (by Google) http://market.android.com/publish/signup

More info to be found here: http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html

But just for developing, no registration is required. You can download the Android SDK for free.